# Deny access to a particular folder based on IP address

Tags: apache, .htaccess, virtualhost

I'm running Apache 2.2.22 on a Debian server, and want to restrict access to a particular directory based on IP address.  I configured the following in my `apache2.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin xxx@xxx.xxx.ac.uk
     DocumentRoot /var/www/webhost
     ServerName webhost.xxx.xxx.ac.uk
     ServerAlias webhost
     ErrorLog  /var/log/apache2/webhost-error.log
     <Directory /var/www/webhost/private/>
         Order deny,allow
         deny from all
         allow 10.0.2.3
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This half works in that from something other than 10.0.2.3 I get a "Forbidden access denied message" as expected, when I type `http://webhost/private/`.

However when I put my fully qualified name in the browser `http://webhost.xxx.xxx.ac.uk/private/` it lets me in.  I've obviously missed something, and hope someone can point out where I've gone wrong here.

I also tried just using `.htaccess` files, but with similar results.

Comment: Most lilkely your request will come from another IP address when using the fully qualified domain name, from your _external_ IP address, since your name resolution will most likely resolve the domain name to that too. That means the request is routed different.

Comment: `.htaccess` style files are not an alternative for such things, they rarely are a good idea actually.

Comment: It should be `Allow from 10.0.2.3`

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick responses.  I tried different cases in case it was picky that way, but none of them worked.  Also tried just not having any allow/Allow lines in, so nothing should be able to access these pages.
Same result.  No access via webhost, but full access via webhost.xxx.xxx.ac.uk

Comment: Also, the web server is an internal intranet, and the IP address is the same for the fully qualified name as for the short form

Comment: Is there maybe another VirtualHost configured?